# How do I use a class as a template in C#?

Tags: c#, class, artificial-intelligence

I'm not sure if I'm asking that correctly, so bear with me. I'm currently attempting to program a neural network. Below is some sample code.

```
using System;
namespace Network
{
    class BaseNeuron
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {
                public int Weight;
                public void sendPulse()
                {
                }
                public void receivePulse()
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically, I want to be able to create multiple instances of the BaseNeuron class, with each "neuron" tied to other "neurons" to make a Neuron Network. Is there any way to do this without having to reiterate this snippet of code for each neuron?

Comment: I don't think your field and methods belong inside your `Main` method :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "_reiterate this snippet of code for each neuron_"? Do you mean you have multiple types of neurons which you want to create classes for?

Comment: Yes: that's the whole point of object oriented programming; you create multiple instances of a type.  In fact, to answer your question, the class *is* the template, already; it's built into the design of the language.  It seems you're in a bit over your head and you should step back and increase your familiarity with basic programming concepts before you try to tackle your domain problem.

Comment: @GrawCube, Yeah, I'm semi-new to C#, so the whole idea of methods and whatnot is still a bit foreign to me, getting the hang of it though.
As for reiterating, it's something along the lines of what you said. I want to have multiple neurons (in order to create a neuron network), so each neuron can interact with the others, based on certain stimuli. Problem is, I can't figure out a way to do this without explicitly typing the code for each individual neuron. (i.e class Neuron0001, class Neuron0002, etc).

Comment: @phoog I find that the best/quickest way for me (personally) to learn is to jump into the depths.

Comment: You can have things like collections of neurons: `List<Neuron> neurons = new List<Neuron>();` Then you can add all the neurons you want: `for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) neurons.Add(new Neuron());`

Comment: @JasperMcKenzie fair enough; that's true for me too.  But I would recommend at least working through the first chapter or two of an elementary programming book.  While you do that, I'd also recommend working some examples on the side that are based on your neuron simulation.  So maybe "before" wasn't the right word :-).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: Jasper, the problem with "just jumping in" is that you'll hit a roadblock, then learn to remove it, hit another, then learn to remove it, and never realize that there's a map which would tell you how to avoid the roadblocks, not only today, but for the rest of your life. Removing roadblocks will not teach you the map. The problem is that the roadblocks do not imply the map.

Comment: @JasperMcKenzie another idea would be to break your problem down into smaller bits first and solve those.  An advantage of programming texts is that they do this for you, and in a progression that introduces language concepts in a logical order.  A disadvantage is that they use example problems that may be meaningless and oversimplified, or at least uninteresting and uninspiring; hence my earlier recommendation.

Comment: Just to be clear: it's "please pick up a book" because I want to see you back here asking _good_ beginner questions. I don't want to have to answer another case of why does the compiler complain when I do `int i = "1";` ?

Comment: One more (last, I hope) bit of advice: the sample code you posted does not compile.  The usual stackoverflow approach would be for you to post the sample code along with the compiler error and say "what am I doing wrong"?  Or, if it compiles but doesn't do what you expect, post your expectations and the actual behavior and say "what am I doing wrong?"  In other words, post a specific problem that can have a specific solution.  This will probably help you work your way to the surface somewhat more methodically.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Totally understandable. The only reason I came here to ask this is due to the fact that after an hour of Google searches (and even checking the 2nd page of the results), I figured I could get an answer quicker if I asked people that know what they're doing.

I think my main problem, though, is that I didn't entirely know WHAT I was looking for, nor how to properly phrase it. So thanks, all your info helped a LOT.

Comment: Like I said, I'm glad you're here, and I'm _ecstatic_ that you're actually listening to comments. ***I really want you back here, and I want more beginners just like you!!!*** You'd be surprised how many beginners don't give themselves a fair chance, by assuming they can just "learn by copying from someone else who learned by copying".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I tend to take advice, especially good (helpful) advice. I'll more than likely stick around.

Comment: My point exactly. People who do that sort of thing are nothing more than wasted minds, IMHO. They're not learning anything. The key to learning is to ask questions, get engaged in whatever it is you're trying to learn. Have fun with it.
Meh. My own opinion, but still.

Comment: Jasper, if you don't know which book to get, I've heard that the _C# Yellow Book_ is good. It's available for free in PDF form here: http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there are some errors in the code you provided:

```
class BaseNeuron
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        public int Weight;

        public void sendPulse()
        {
        }

        public void receivePulse()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It should be:

```
class BaseNeuron
{            
    //class field
    public int Weight;

    //class method
    public void SendPulse(/*Parameters ...*/)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    //class method
    public void ReceivePulse(/*Parameters ...*/)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }            
}
```

Notice that the `Main` is gone. Classes normally don't have a `Main` method, which is usually just the *entry point* of the application (the first function to get executed when the program runs).

Basically, each class is a *template for objects*, which means you can create new **instances** of the class by using the `new` keyword, like this:

```
//creating two seperate neurons
neuron1 = new BaseNeuron();
neuron2 = new BaseNeuron();

//Notice that each SendPulse is called on separate objects!
neuron1.SendPulse();
neuron2.SendPulse();
```

I suggest you read a little bit about class (maybe [here](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/)) to get a better understanding how this works.

Alright, so now we have our class figured out. You said we wanted to make a network which consists of several neurons, which are instances of the class above.
So, what you will probably want to do is:

```
class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //the size of the network
        int size = 5;

        //create array of Neurons
        BaseNeuron[] network = new BaseNeuron[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < network.length; i++)
        {
            //actually create a new nueron (instantiate them)
            network[i] = new BaseNeuron();

            //link up neurons together, etc
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the implementation depends of the internal implementation of the `BaseNeuron` class. You also might need to create a `NeuralNetwork` class to contain the above code and related functions.

Comment: You skipped a step. A pretty important one.

Comment: I just explained the general approach, but please, do enlighten me

Comment: You never instantiated the neurons. Creating an array of a reference type doesn't fill in the references.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Saunders Of course, I assumed it to be trivial. Nevertheless I'll fix it shortly. My bad.

Comment: That "trivial" thing is the source of a huge number of programming bugs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders and given the OP's degree of familiarity with object oriented programming concepts, hardly anything could be assumed to be trivial at this point.

Comment: So let me get this straight.

`neuron1 = new BaseNeuron();`

In order to create a new neuron, that's all I'd have to do? So if I wanted to create a thousand neurons, I'd simple create a loop that generates them (based on that code), right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's all you have to do. A class is a "template" for objects. All of the objects created from the class are instances of the class. Simple OO that you might not otherwise learn on your own. Please pick up a book.

Comment: @JasperMcKenzie that's basically it.  Another key concept is "separation of concerns": the "main" method has the job of putting your program into action.  That should not generally be a concern of your neuron class or classes, whose concern is to model your problem domain.

Comment: @phoog You're right, every bit is important at this point. xD